# Launching the application to work with https

Tags: asp.net, docker, https, kestrel-http-server

There is an application on aspnet which should work on https. The application is deployed in a container.

Dockerfile.yml

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

WORKDIR /app_service
COPY app_service/ ./

EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./UserManager.dll"]
```

When I run

```
docker run -d -p 443:443 author/app_service:v1.0
```

I get

```
curl -vLk https://<ip>/app
*   Trying <ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to <ip> port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to <ip> port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip> port 443: Connection refused
```

But

```
curl -vLk https://127.0.0.1/app
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:443
```

How to properly build and run a container to work with https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly, I would not recommend to use this in production environment due to MITM attack, just answering to your question;** your certificate has a domain 127.0.0.1 but not your external IP you need to include that IP into your certificate, which means that you need to generate a new certificate which has 127.0.0.1 and your external domain.

*The best practice is using https protocol for external network communication and using http protocol for the internal network communication, this approach brings us reverse-proxy service to do that. this is an example article how to configure reverse proxy with docker https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-docker-compose/*